# How to draw a graph from data in a database in VS

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-2017

My problem is the following:

I have a database which I want to get graphics from but it is in postgresql and I have not found information on how to graph this type of db, I found an example of MySQL so I took it as a reference since it is SQL and try to graph according to this but at the time of making the graph what draws is a huge X of red that crosses from corner to corner and then for more than I try to see that it is the error I can not find, I leave here the code.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String parametros = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=root;Database=test;";
        NpgsqlConnection con;
        String query = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public void conectar()
        {

            try
            {
                con = new NpgsqlConnection(parametros);
                con.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("conexion exitosa");
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conectar();
            //chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].LegendText = "Grafica de partes";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "partnum";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "coutn(partnum)";
            chart1.DataSource = EnviarDatos("SELECT partnum, count(partnum) FROM logbook GROUP BY partnum;");

            con.Close();

        }
        public DataTable EnviarDatos(string consulta)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            NpgsqlDataAdapter add = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(consulta, con);
            add.Fill(table);
            return table;

        }
    }
```

The query I send is one that throws the number of the part and another that throws the numbers of times that number was used, but no matter how hard you try not to draw the graph, the first is a string and the second is an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the `YValueMembers`. It would be easier to rename it also:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "cnt";
chart1.DataSource = EnviarDatos("SELECT partnum, count(partnum) as cnt FROM logbook GROUP BY partnum;");
```